# How should we tag the Yu-Gi-Oh! series?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

*[Yu-Gi-Oh!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!)* is a media franchise primarily consisting of manga and anime (along with a trading card game). Over the last 20+ years, it's spawned seven different anime series (two of which are different adaptations of the same manga series).

Naturally, this site has the tag [yu-gi-oh](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh), but it seems to cover all 7 series. Looking at them, they are about:

- Original series: 19
- GX: 2
- 5D's: 2
- VRAINS: 1
- Original series and GX: 1
- Original series and Zexal: 1
- Arc-V and VRAINS: 1
- Kazuki Takahashi (series creator): 2
- Franchise as a whole/Unspecified: 4

Some of them are about the manga specifically, others are about the anime specifically, and some of them are open to answers for either.

What is the best way to tag these? Do we just want a tag for each series (covering both the manga and anime) along with [yu-gi-oh-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-series) and call it a day? Or does another tagging system make sense?

*[It's time to t-t-t-t-t-t-t-tag!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFkdcQgNJHo)*

Comment: Personally, I think a single tag for Yu-Gi-Oh!, and other anime/manga, would suffice. Much cleaner. Less hassle when retagging.

Comment: @W.Are My concern is that the different series have little to nothing in common with them aside from the fact that they play the same card game. It's more like Kamen Rider or Super Sentai in that they have different characters and sometimes different rules to their universe, but all have the same conceit (and occasionally cross over).

Comment: Okay but the fact remains that the franchise is related to a particular card game with a particular deck, different from other card games like Cardfight Vanguard, if I recall correctly, regardless if the plot or characters between each series are never connected. Maybe if it has more questions then separate tags might be necessary for each series but as it stands, it has around 32 questions so far and anyone looking for info or questions won't have a hard time finding them. But I'm not a mod so the final say is from them. Just expressing what I thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the current lack of popularity with the series. It's no necessary a priority, but breaking up the series into tags would be helpful as they are pretty distinct from one another.

GX, 5D's, Zexals, Arc-V, V-Rains, etc. are distinctly spin-offs (Like *Railgun* is to *Index*) of the original series (even if they share the same universe and timeline) and should not be grouped with the "original" series.

Ideally we can do something like this:

[yu-gi-oh-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-series) General franchise tag

[yu-gi-oh-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-manga) Inclusive of the original manga and the R series (even if it's canonicity is in question)

[yu-gi-oh-movies](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-movies) All the movies including the 1999 Toei movie.

[yu-gi-oh-novels](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-novels) For the novel stuff that didn't really come out here (not a big thing compared to Japan).

[yu-gi-oh](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh) the "original" anime series including the 1998 Toei series, Duel Monsters series by Gallop (including the Capsule Monsters part that was not released in Japan).

Spinoff series such as [yu-gi-oh-gx](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-gx), [yu-gi-oh-5ds](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-5ds), [yu-gi-oh-zexals](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-zexals), [yu-gi-oh-arc-v](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-arc-v),[yu-gi-oh-v-rains](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-v-rains), should be tagged as appropriate, and future titles should use the `[yu-gi-oh` + `series-name` + `]` as applicable within the bounds of the maximum length and formatting of SE tags.

Avoid redundant tagging where applicable. If you want to compare the original series and a spin off , jus use the two series tags sand don't include the franchise tags unless it's there is some relation of the entire franchise itself, like "Why is the canonicity of Yu-Gi-Oh! R disputed, despite being being set in the same universe and supervised by the original series creator?" would have [yu-gi-oh-manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-manga) and [yu-gi-oh-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-series). Maybe a tag for the creator himself. No need to use the [yu-gi-oh](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh) tag.

Comment: Ideally these guidelines should be in the tag wiki for better reference, when needed to direct people.